# PayPal iOS SDK - Payment not available for apps with a Mobile SDK type of integration

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, paypal

I'm making and iPad app which uses the PayPal iOS SDK for payments. The problem is that I cannot Log in to PayPal from the app. I can only pay by credit card.

When you create an application on the PayPal developer page there is this message:

> **Important: Currently, Log in with PayPal is not available for apps with a Mobile SDK type of integration.**

So my question are:

1.When will it be available?

2.If I publish my app now will it work when it will be available or I will need to update?

3.Why there is login button? It confuses the user. They have a button for login but they can only pay by credit card.

[You can see the screen by clicking this link.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zcOI.png)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Josh from PayPal here. My apologies -- I think the messaging here could be improved.

*Log In with PayPal* is an [oauth2](http://oauth.net/2/) identity service, which you could use (say) to let users log in to your app using their PayPal account instead of having to create an account with your service.

The log in button you see in the PayPal Mobile SDKs, in contrast, is intended to let folks *pay using their PayPal wallet*, which does require that they log in. This does work, now, with a "Mobile SDK type of integration".

Hope that clears things up a bit.